# Android PayUMoney integration error "some error occured"

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am trying to integrate PayUMoney payment gateway in my android app, I am not sure what is happening with it. Even If I have generated hash from server and followed exactly the same procedure provided on [PayUMoney website](https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/mobilecheckout/android.html)

I am getting TOAST message **some error occured**. Event landing page is not loaded, as soon as I move from checkout page to payU spinner rotates a while and after that I get TOAST message and I land back to my checkout page.

**PayUMoney Code**

```
 String serverCalculatedHash = getHashFromServer();

     PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam.Builder builder = new PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam.Builder();
                            builder.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(paymentAmount))                        
                                    .setTxnId(transactionId)                                            
                                    .setPhone(phoneNumber)                                              
                                    .setProductName(productName)                                        
                                    .setFirstName(firstName)                                            
                                    .setEmail(emailId)                                                  
                                    .setsUrl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php")
                                    .setfUrl("https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php")
                                    .setUdf1(udf1)
                                    .setUdf2(udf2)
                                    .setUdf3(udf3)
                                    .setUdf4(udf4)
                                    .setUdf5(udf5)
                                    .setUdf6("")
                                    .setUdf7("")
                                    .setUdf8("")
                                    .setUdf9("")
                                    .setUdf10("")
                                    .setIsDebug(true)                                                     
                                    .setKey(merchentKey)                                                  
                                    .setMerchantId(merchentId); 

 PayUmoneySdkInitializer.PaymentParam paymentParam = builder.build();
                            paymentParam.setMerchantHash(serverCalculatedHash);
 PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(paymentParam, CheckoutActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme_default, true);
```

**Console Log**

> 09-16 21:07:21.488 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/hash:
>   cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e
>   09-16 21:07:21.489 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: key - mJ5aor0Z
>   09-16 21:07:21.489 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: merchantId -
>   5710201 09-16 21:07:21.489 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: txnid -
>   1505576241249 09-16 21:07:21.489 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param ::
>   amount - 10.0 09-16 21:07:21.489 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param ::
>   SURL - https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php 09-16
>   21:07:21.489 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: FURL -
>   https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php 09-16
>   21:07:21.489 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: productInfo - product
>   name 09-16 21:07:21.489 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: email -
>   xyz@gmail.com 09-16 21:07:21.489 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param ::
>   firstName - MyName 09-16 21:07:21.489 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app
>   D/param :: phone - 9999014250 09-16 21:07:21.489
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: udf1 - udf1 09-16 21:07:21.489
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: udf2 - udf2 09-16 21:07:21.489
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: udf3 - udf3 09-16 21:07:21.489
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: udf4 - udf4 09-16 21:07:21.489
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: udf5 - udf5 09-16 21:07:21.489
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: udf6 -  09-16 21:07:21.490
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: udf7 -  09-16 21:07:21.490
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: udf8 -  09-16 21:07:21.490
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: udf9 -  09-16 21:07:21.490
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/param :: udf10 -  09-16 21:07:21.526
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app I/WebViewFactory: Loading
>   com.google.android.webview version 60.0.3112.116 (code 311211650)
>   09-16 21:07:21.569 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app I/art: Rejecting re-init
>   on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class
>   09-16 21:07:21.569 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app I/art: Rejecting re-init
>   on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class
>   09-16 21:07:21.572 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app I/art: Rejecting re-init
>   on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class
>   09-16 21:07:21.572 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app I/art: Rejecting re-init
>   on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class
>   09-16 21:07:21.579 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time
>   to load native libraries: 1 ms (timestamps 6391-6392) 09-16
>   21:07:21.596 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app I/chromium:
>   [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(144)] Chromium logging enabled: level =
>   0, default verbosity = 0 09-16 21:07:21.596 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app
>   I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number
>   "60.0.3112.116", actual native library version number "60.0.3112.116"
>   09-16 21:07:21.622 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app I/cr_BrowserStartup:
>   Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true 09-16 21:07:21.858
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
>   09-16 21:07:21.858 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/EgretLoader: The context
>   is not activity 09-16 21:07:21.921 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app
>   D/payumoneySDK - login:
>   {"event_id":"1","device_id":"739bbf12ec1be70e","uuid":"0b500414-dff6-4f21-bfdf-aed66a78d150","d_ua":"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 Build/MMB29M; wv)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0
>   Chrome/60.0.3102.110 Mobile
>   Safari/537.36","u_lat":"","u_lon":"","u_acu":"","app_id":"in.co.sd.app","package_name":"in.co.sd.app","app_version_name":"1.0","app_version_code":"1","d_locale":"en","d_ccid":"in","d_lang":"English","d_name":"Xiaomi","d_model":"Redmi
>   Note
>   3","d_os":"Android","d_osv":"6.0.1","sdk_version":"7","sdk_build":"7.0.0","d_mfg":"Xiaomi","d_nw_type":"WIFI","d_ss":"4","d_scrn_sz":"5.7437176737064215","d_scrn_res":"1080
>   * 1920","m_id":"5773251","m_key":"mJ5aor0Z","ip":"10.107.124.9","app_name":"Service
>   Service","d_ts":"1505576241915","env":"DEBUG"} 09-16 21:07:22.076
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request
>   time:58596890 09-16 21:07:22.183 20712-20712/in.co.sd.app
>   V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@f0846b7 09-16 21:07:22.183
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@49c0e24 09-16 21:07:22.216
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app D/ActivityThreadInjector:
>   clearCachedDrawables. 09-16 21:07:22.255 20712-11058/in.co.sd.app
>   W/System: Ignoring header UserSessionCookiePageUrl because its value
>   was null. 09-16 21:07:23.193 20712-20718/in.co.sd.app W/art:
>   Suspending all threads took: 5.983ms 09-16 21:07:23.195
>   20712-20712/in.co.sd.app I/Difference: [ main: SdkSession.java: 365:
>   onResponse() ] --> URL=/payment/app/v1/addPaymentTime=978 09-16
>   21:07:23.325 20712-20784/in.co.sd.app V/RenderScript: 0x557e7de550
>   Launching thread(s), CPUs 6

Comment: did u find any solution

Comment: I am not sure if it will work for you as well, but I did not do much in my case SURL & FURL was not correct.

Comment: PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(paymentParam, CheckoutActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme_default, true); this nline causing me error..showing loading symbol and getting some error occured. even in on activity result the intent data is nulll

Answer (score 0):

I think I am late to answer, but still,
I faced similar issue, Key and Salt are not correct.
you need to contact payUMoney support, they will provide you new Key,, Salt and MID.
Also they will provide you php code to generate serverHash,

If you want to test your Key and salt, download this sample app(https://github.com/payu-intrepos/payumoney-new-sample-app) 
from payumoney and configure AppEnvironment class with your parameters, hope this helps!

Comment: can you please provide code for same support is taking almost 2 weeks still not contacted me @Harshad